# GUI Unit Testing via Macro Recording

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I recently got the assignment to write a unit test for an existing standalone Java GUI Application.

Up to this point I have written an application that allows one to create macros by recording mouse- and keyboardinput (and the time between single events) and execute these macros. This works for checking the application for critical errors, but there is currently no possibility of checking the data of the underlying GUI.
It would be very nice if I could check the data via JUnit (assertequals etc).

How can I accomplish this? Is this a case for reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unless writing the framework was part of your assignment, i'd recommend avoiding re-inventing the wheel.

there are various frameworks for testing swing UI's, almost all of which support junit.
have a look at [fest-swing](http://fest.easytesting.org/), for exaple, which allows you to test your UI components from Junit. it also allows you to assert properties of the underlining UI (so assert that a certain table should have 5 rows after a button is clicked, ot that a particular widget should be in a particular state etc)

its best to combine this with either a mock "backend" that you implement yourself or use a mocking likrary to simulate your server/business-logic - for that have a look at [mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/)

Comment: Thank you radai, I just played around with the FEST-Framework. I was afraid it couldn't handle our custom GUI components, but it works like a charm and is exactly what I need! My solution was really kind of reinventing the wheel :)

Comment: @cutze - glad i could help. if it worked would you mind marking this as the correct answer? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm skeptical of the program design.  The presentation layer sounds like it has business logic.  This is bad.

I suggest refactoring the code so this isn't the case.  Each GUI action should correspond to calls to the logic layer.  The logic layer should have unit tests, not so much the presentation layer unless presentation is complex.

Comment: The unit-testing application is standalone at the moment. It just gives us the ability to record our mouse and keyboard actions and replay them.

The existing main-application is already quite large and most of the GUI components are company-internal, so their functionality should be tested as well.

Comment: Then write unit tests for the logic layer.  Don't test the logic layer through the GUI.  It doesn't give as good coverage or as thorough a range of values. Even if the GUI layer is tied into the logic layer, just create a form and test it programatically.  I wouldn't bother with the macro.